# Java SimpleDateFormat Exception: unparseable date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I am trying to get Java to read in a date formatted as follows:
Thu Mar 8 13:33:25 2012 
But getting an unparseable exception. Here's the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String currentDate = "Thu Mar 8 13:33:25 2012";
Date date2 = formatter.parse(currentDate);
```

It throws the following exception:    `Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Mar 8 13:33:25 2012"`

Could someone help me out please? I've tried changing the "d" to "dd" but still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that you are using _formatter_ instead of _formatter2_ .

Comment: You have `formatter2` `SimpleDateFormat` object and you are using `formatter` to parse. Where does `formatter` comes from?

Comment: This code works if you user `formatter2` instead of `formatter`.

Comment: When I use `formatter2`, I get absolutely **no** errors and the code runs.

Comment: @Patrick will the code fail if System does not have English Locale?

Comment: Thanks guys - that's correct. I had another formatter object and accidentally used that. Phew.

Comment: @Zainab Abaid don't forget to vote for the correct answer and accept. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `formatter2` variable as specified in your example.

Your code works when using `formatter2`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String currentDate = "Thu Mar 8 13:33:25 2012";
Date date2 = formatter2.parse(currentDate);
System.out.println(date2);
```

Result:

> Thu Mar 08 13:33:25 CAT 2012

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = "EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("en", "IN"));

String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
```